# Why do tailwind breakpoints not work in this case with Next.js?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, postcss, jss

I have a component that should hide an element if the viewport is below the md breakpoint. It looks as follows:

```
function HideUnderBreakpoint({
  breakpoint,
  children,
}: {
  breakpoint: "xs" | "sm" | "md" | "xl";
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return <div className={`block max-${breakpoint}:hidden`}>{children}</div>;
}
```

However, when I use this in Next.js, there will be no CSS rules for the class max-something:hidden when inspecting it in the browser.

I have noted that modifying the return value to this generates the class as intended - admittedly ignoring the breakpoint prop:

`` return <div className={`block max-md:hidden`}>{children}</div>; ``

But you can now create several of these components and conditionally render the relevant one - and the classes will work as intended.

This seems strange to me, since the breakpoint prop never changes during the lifetime of the component. I would expect Next.js to "just work". I am not certain if the issue is specific to tailwind, postcss, Next.js or even react-jss, which is also present in the project.

Why does this work and the other one does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tailwind uses regex to find class names, and because of this they need to exist as unbroken strings in your source code. A consequence of this is [you cannot use string interpolation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) the way you're trying to do, as Tailwind will not be able to find the class name.

What you can do instead is map your props to static class names:

```js
function HideUnderBreakpoint({
  breakpoint,
  children,
}: {
  breakpoint: "xs" | "sm" | "md" | "xl";
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const sizeVariants = {
    xs: 'max-xs:hidden',
    sm: 'max-sm:hidden',
    md: 'max-md:hidden',
    xl: 'max-xl:hidden',
  }

  return <div className={`block ${sizeVariants[breakpoint]}`}>{children}</div>;
}
```